# Iterating over the values of a python dict and simultaneous update

Tags: python, dictionary

I wonder how to iterate over the values and update simultaneously a python's dict. Why the following code does not work?

```
for values in First_Dict.values():
    if True:
        Second_Dict= Function(values)
        First_Dict.update(Second_Dict)
```

There is a solution, but it is not very elegant. It includes a list and iter(). Obviously, I do not care about the keys.

```
tempList = [i for i in First_Dict.values()]
iterator = iter(tempList)
while True:  
    try:   
        TempIterator = iterator.next()  
    except StopIteration:
        break  
        if True:
            Second_Dict= Function(values)
            for j in Second_Dict.values():  
                tempList.append(j)
```

Comment: Could you post an example input and expected output? It's very unclear what exactly you are asking.

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do?  What is `Second_Dict`?  Calling `update` multiple times on the same dict with the same argument won't have any additional effect.  Also, why do you have `if True`?

Comment: @Bill The input is one dictionary, the output would be bigger dictionary if a condition is true.

Comment: @BrenBam: I am trying to update a dictionary on the go if some condition over the values is True. The update will be with another dictionary. The type of the content does not matter for the logic to work.

Comment: @BrenBarn: The Second_Dict is an output of a function in the body if the condition is True, so it is not the same in every update. Indeed with every value of First_Dict the Second_Dict will be different (or 0-sized).

Comment: @Ivaylo: Then it would be helpful to give a more illustrative example.  An example that uses undefined variables and a meaningless `if True` is confusing and doesn't make it clear what you want.

Comment: I thought that pseudo-code would be easier to discuss. I am sorry that I was not clear from the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overcomplicating things; just use `list()` on `dict.values()` to create a copy and avoid getting the `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration` exception:

```
for value in list(First_Dict.values()):
    if True:
        First_Dict.update(Second_Dict)
```

If you need a dynamically growing list, store the list first, then loop:

```
values = list(First_dict.values())
for value in values:
    if True:
        values.extend(Second_Dict.values())
```

This of course does not update the original dictionary, just extend the `values` list.

This assumes you are using Python 3; in Python 2, `dict.values()` already returns a list copy, not a dictionary view; you'd use `values = First_dict.values()` directly instead.

Comment: As somebody has mentioned it here before - don't change your wheels whilst driving. ;)

Comment: @kroolik: in this case it is entirely clear what the destination is, let alone the vehicle or, indeed, if the OP is driving at all. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much Martijn. The second solution is more elegant than mine for sure. Interestingly enough your first solution does not work (gives the same output as my question). I guess, because the list, which was created with list(First_Dict.values()) will not be updated even if First_Dict is updated. By the way in my original question I do not get RunTimeError. Python is 2.7.5+.

Comment: How can I force a dictionary view, instead of the list of values?

Comment: @Ivaylo: Use [`dict.viewvalues()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.viewvalues). You cannot alter the dictionary while iterating, however.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: You are right, I cannot change a dictionary while iterating over it. The solution with a intermediate list would be preferable I guess. You are very helpful, thank you.